# android sharedpreferences return with null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am developing a "book an appointment" application for android mobiles which have Users I have a User class for it, with properties userID, email, name, password and phonenumber. And I have different activities which are using it.
I want to store those data in the `Sharedpreference`. But something goes wrong, in the `storeUserData()` in debug mode, there are all the data in the `user`. And in the `setUserLoggedIn()` I added to the same preference a `boolean`, but somehow it returns `false`. And the end the `user = null`.... But I call `setUserLoggedIn` like this:

```
private void logUserIn(User returnedUser) {

    userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
}
```

So I give it a `true` value. What have I missed? How should I get those data from `storeUserData`?
Here's the code:

```
public void storeUserData(User user){
    SharedPreferences.Editor userLocalDatabaseEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putInt("userID", user.userID);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("name", user.name);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("email", user.email);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("password", user.password);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("phonenumber", user.phonenumber);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.commit(); //May I should use apply() ?
}

public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn){
    SharedPreferences.Editor userLocalDatabaseEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putBoolean("LoggedIn", loggedIn);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.commit();
}

public User getLoggedInUser(){

    if(userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("loggedIn", false) == false){
        return null;
    }

    int userID = userLocalDatabase.getInt("userID", -1);
    String name = userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
    String email = userLocalDatabase.getString("email", "");
    String password = userLocalDatabase.getString("password", "");
    String phonenumber = userLocalDatabase.getString("phonenumber", "");
    //String name, String username, String password, String email, String phonenumber
    User user = new User(userID, name, email, password, phonenumber);

    return user;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to be storing that much data then it might be a better idea to store them in SQLite instead of in Shared Preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting wrong `key` here. It must be `LoggedIn` instead of `loggedIn`. So your code should be:

```
public User getLoggedInUser(){
    if(userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false) == false){
        return null;
    }
}
```